# UART communication problems with CO2 sensor and STM32 Nucleo board

Tags: embedded, stm32, sensors, uart

I'm trying to measure CO2 concentration in ppm, but I'm having issues to receive the data from the sensor.
The sensor is [Explorir-M-20](https://www.co2meter.com/products/explorir-10-co2-smart-led-sensor) ([datasheet](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0019/5952/files/ExplorIR-M_Data_Sheet_Rev_4.11.pdf)) and uses UART communication protocol. The board that I'm using is the STM32 Nucleo L6A6ZG. I'm using the pin PD9 and PD8, for RX and TX transmission at the baud rate of 9600 Bits/s. The word length is set at 8 bits with 1 stop bit.

I tried, first, the UART communication both in polling (see code below) and in interrupt mode, with no success, it always shows as RxBuffer 0. The HAL status are always OK state, there are no errors.

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef ret_uart;
uint8_t buf_uart[12];
uint8_t TxBuffer[5]="Z\r\n";
uint8_t RxBuffer[9] = {0};
uint8_t co2[3] = {0};
int co2_ppm = 0;

int readCO2(void){
    ret_uart = HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, (uint8_t *)TxBuffer, sizeof(TxBuffer),100);
    if (ret_uart != HAL_OK){
        strcpy((char*)buf_uart, "Error Tx\r\n");
    }
    else{
        HAL_Delay(4000);
        ret_uart = HAL_UART_Receive(&huart3, (uint8_t *)RxBuffer, sizeof(RxBuffer),100);
        if (ret_uart != HAL_OK){
            strcpy((char*)buf_uart, "Error Rx\r\n");
        }
        else{
            co2[0] = RxBuffer[5] - '0';
            co2[1] = RxBuffer[6] - '0';
            co2[2] = RxBuffer[7] - '0';
            co2_ppm = (1000 * co2[0]) + (100 * co2[1]) + (10*co2[2]);
        }
    }
}
```

So I tried to use protocol analyzer, to check if the sensor received or transmitted something from the board and in fact, when the sensor receives the command "Z\r\n" (request measure), and transmits immediately the measured data (see photo below). I actually don't understand why the measured data from the sensor is not recorded by the STM32 board.

[Protocol Analyzer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCeQh.png)

---

Update 1

I removed the 4 seconds of delay and I also reduced the size of TxBuffer with 3 bytes, instead of 5, as @pmacfarlane suggested. I set 5 bytes first, because I considered also the quotation marks ('' or ""). In the meantime, I added the UART receive in the interrupt mode and also added the command line "K 2\r\n". This allows to set in polling mode the sensor, such that the sensor keeps take measurement in background, and the output will be streamed  once is requested.

```
ret_uart = HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, (uint8_t *)TxBuffer, sizeof(TxBuffer),100);
HAL_Delay(100);
ret_uart = HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, (uint8_t *)Kmode, sizeof(Kmode),100);
```

Now, it kind works. The problem now, is that once it takes a measurement, it won't be updated, it keeps saving the same value on RxBuffer, meanwhile in the "Protocol Analyzer" shows new measurement, as you can see from the picture. I set a buffer that saves all measurements, but it keep saving the same value. Why it doesn't refresh or take new measurements?
Any advice to solve this problem?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Z5Uh.png)

Comment: It's because you delay for 4 seconds before trying to read from the UART. The sensor sends its answer immediately, while you are delaying, and you miss it. The UART doesn't have a hardware buffer.

Comment: Also note that if the sensor does not send 9 or more bytes in the response, then the `HAL_UART_Receive()` will timeout after 100ms, and you will take the "error" code path, even if it has received, say, 8 bytes.

Comment: @pmacfarlane I tried to put a delay of 100ms, instead of 4 seconds, and it won't transmit nothing. In the protocol analyzer it just print question marks.
Regarding the length of RxBuffer, it's correct, because it's fixed, since it's a sensor that measures till 100'000 ppm.

Comment: I don't think you want any delay at all. There is no buffer, any delay makes it more likely you're going to miss the response.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the main problem is your 4 second delay between sending the `Z` command, and receiving the response.

```
HAL_Delay(4000);
```

There is no indication that you need to wait for four seconds before receiving a response. The sensor will send back the response immediately, while you are delaying, and you will miss it.

If you were using an operating system like Linux or Windows, the OS would buffer up any incoming data, and you could read it 4 seconds (or 4 hours) later. This is not the case on a bare-metal system like the STM32 using the HAL. If you have not initiated a UART receive, then any data sent from the sensor will be lost.

You need to remove the `HAL_Delay()` completely, and immediately start a receive.

There is a hypothetical situation that the sensor could respond before you call `HAL_UART_Receive()`, but with a UART running at 9600 baud it is most unlikely.

Also note that your `HAL_UART_Transmit()` sends 5 bytes when it should only be sending 3. This may (or may not) be harmless.

Comment: I followed your advices, as you can you can see from the update, but when I take a new measurement it keep the old measurement. It doesn' refresh. Why?

Comment: "I added the UART receive in the interrupt mode" - you can either receive in interrupt mode, or in polling mode. If you're trying to do both at the same time, that won't work.

Comment: I'm not trying to take measuremets both in polling or interrupt. I'm using only in interrupt mode the uart reception and in polling mode the transmission. The sensor has 3 different method of operation: in command, streaming or polling mode, which is apart from the uart reception code of the board. I'm doing it in a wrong way, perhaps?

Comment: You are calling `HAL_UART_Receive_IT()`, which starts the reception, but does not wait for it to complete. Then you are immediately taking data from the buffer and using it, before it has been received from the UART. You'll need to wait for the receive to complete. So, you'd be just as well to use `HAL_UART_Receive()`, which will wait for the reception to complete.